# In jQuery, IE object doesn't support this property or method, can someone help?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have been pulling out my hair on this topic.  I have been searching google and could not find much to help me.  I have this here:
http://www.fissiondesigns.com/simon

Works in FF and chrome, but can't get it to work on IE, keep getting an error 'object doesnt support this property or method'.  I looked it up on google and couldn't find any examples that pertain to my problem.  If anyone could help that would be great!  thanks.

Comment: Could you please past here the exact peace of code, which makes you troubles?

Comment: Well he posted the URL of the site, and sure enough it gets exactly the error he says it does when you try and load the page in IE.

Answer (score 2):

```
.draggable({
            containment: image.canvas,

        });
        return this;
```

Should be (in jquery.pinpoint.js):

```
.draggable({
            containment: image.canvas
        });
        return this;
```

And:

```
area.resizable({
       handles: 'all',
      containment:image.canvas,

       })
```

should be

```
area.resizable({
       handles: 'all',
       containment:image.canvas
    })
```

So, basically as [Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172761/in-jquery-ie-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method-can-someone-help/3172801#3172801) has said, you've got a few commas that shouldn't be there.

Comment: I think the call to "resizable" right above that has a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that "pinpoint" plugin has a stray comma (line 179); it's where it calls `area.resizable` in the object literal passed in.

The IE8 debugger — unlike it's virtually worthless predecessor for IE6 — actually works pretty well, and made it quite clear what was going on. (Well, not totally clear; IE doesn't say "you have a stray comma".)